# How to find the shortest path between two nodes within array of objects?

Tags: javascript, database, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have 10,000+ data (`Users`) coming from an API in JSON format and given two nodes (i.e. 2 `Users`), I would like to find the shortest path between two `Users`.

When I realized that to find the shortest path, I could use Dijkstra's algorithm, but then to do that, I have to create a graph which is not sufficient with 10,000+ data.

For example, I make an API request

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
)
```

Where each user is an object

```
  {
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "address": {...}
    },
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": [
      "Romaguera-Crona",
      "Google",
      "Facebook"
    ]
  }
```

And the problem is to see how two users are related to one another based on the company that they work for

I simply can't start on this because the data is so huge. I would just like to know, how can we go about this? Do we create a graph and apply Dijkstra's algorithm?

All I've done is to really loop through each User and check companies array.

```js
Users.filter(user => user.companies.include([...]))
```

Comment: I think this question is also related to database not only javascript.

Comment: I think you should construct a graph with a vertex for each user  and each company, then go through the list of users and add an edge between the user vertex and the vertices of all companies belonging to the user data. Then run the shortest path algorithm on this graph. I cannot help with the implementation, I don't know if there is a library for graph theory in javascript.

Comment: When you get the data from the API, are you using that data only once for 2 users or will you be accessing it multiple times? I am no expert in this field, but if you are accessing it multiple times then one idea that comes to mind is to convert the array into an indexed map where the index is the persons name. Once you have that you can get a person's information by their name without having to loop through an array. It's just an idea, I don't know how that holds up against other options.

Comment: @SamHerrmann I'm only using it once.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is the original problem that you reduced to the question in [How to create edges between nodes that have similarities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55525886/how-to-create-edges-between-nodes-that-have-similarities). Your reduction is useful, but without knowing the nature of the data, namely, that it represents companies a person worked for, the problem becomes more general. Because this is real-life data, we can assume some things about it, like users on average don't have more than 10 job entries, and not all users have worked at the same company. This means the graph will be rather sparse.

To construct the  users graph, you can go with my second suggestion from the other post:

- Build a map from a company name to the set of all users that have worked for this company
- Iterate over company names, iterate over all pairs of users that have worked for each company, and connect them with an edge if they aren't connected yet

This can still be a rather large graph: for 10k users you might end up with a million edges if users have worked with 100 other users on average. However, it's nothing a modern computer can't store in RAM. I'm not sure how memory-efficient Javascript is though - if you are open to switching to a more performant language, you could consider that option.

Now you have a graph and want to find a shortest path between two nodes (repeatedly, I assume). Note that since your graph does not have weights, Djikstra's algorithm is not necessary. You can run a BFS which works in `O(N+M)` time, where N is the number of users and M is the number of edges. For a million edges, it could comfortably run within a second in Java, but might take several in Javascript.