# How to create edges between nodes that have similarities

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I have a simple Graph class, and I have to create the graph with nodes and edges. There is an edge between two nodes, `nodeA`, `nodeB` if the array on `nodeA` and `nodeB` has some similarities.

For example:

```
const example = [{
  "node": "A",
  "data": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}, {
  "node": "B",
  "data": [ 3, 4, 5 ]
}, {
  "node": "C",
  "data": [ 5, 6, 7 ]
}, {
  "node": "D",
  "data": [ 7, 8, 9 ]
}]
```

This means that there is an edge between:

1. `A` and `B` because 3 apears on both `data` arrays.
2. `B` and `C` because 5 apears on both `data` arrays.
3. `C` and `D` because 7 apears on both `data` arrays.

So essentially we have an edge from `A -> B -> C -> D`

I managed to create a graph and use adjacency list for storing edges, but the problem is, I don't know how to create edges between nodes that have similarity. The naive solution would be to look at `example[i - 1]` and `example[i]`. But this is wrong because the data do not come in order.

```
class Graph {

  constructor(numOfVertex) {

    this.adj = new Map();

  }

  addNodes(node) {

    this.adj.set(node, []);  

  }

  addEdge(nodeA, nodeB) {

    this.adj.get(nodeA).push(nodeB);

    this.adj.get(nodeA).push(nodeB);

  };

}
```

and to populate the graph, I do:

```
    const graph = new Graph(example.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {

      const { node, data } = example[i];

      graph.addVertex(title)

      G.addEdge(...)

    }
```

Any ideas of how I can loop through the data array of each node to see similarities efficiently?

For the sake of the question, I gave a small example data, in reality, I loop through a large set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of `data` arrays and sparsity of the resulting graph, there is several ways you can approach this problem:

- Iterate over all pairs of nodes and compute whether they have an edge. This computation can be performed in `O(|data[A]| + |data[B]|)` for a pair of nodes (A, B), so the complexity of this solution is `O(N^2 + N * (sum of data[i] over all i))`. This works well if you graph is dense, i.e., number of edges in it is on the order of N<sup>2</sup>.
- Build a map (X -> ListOfNodes), such that each number X is mapped to all nodes that contain X in their data. Every pair of nodes that belongs to the same list should be connected with an edge. The complexity of this solution is `O((sum of data[i] over all i) + (a hard to estimate quantity that is the number of times each pair of nodes shares a data point))`. For sparse graphs, this should work better than the previous approach, but it really depends on how data arrays are constructed.

How is your data generated?

Comment: The data is coming from an API in JSON format shown as above. The problem isn't really in the array construction, but rather how we iterate through the data and find similarity between nodes.

Comment: The complexity O(N^2 + N * (sum of data[i] over all i)) won't be sufficient as data can be 100,000 nodes.

Comment: @Doodoo Do you have any restrictions or estimates on data size? For example, are data arrays always comprised of 3 elements, or is there some other upper limit? Are numbers from some predefined range or they can be any integers?